# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './descargas'

Tags: python, python-3.x, blob

Estoy descargado archivos de un repositorio en azure con las librerías

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobClient
```

al momento de intentar descargar el archivo desde el blob de la siguiente manera

```
with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
```

me da error de permisos

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './descargas'
```

El script es descarga.py y la carpeta es descargas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué permisos tiene la carpeta donde se corre el script y el script?
Para saber eso, dentro de la carpeta donde corres el script da un `ls -l`.

Comment: @Cuauhtli Ya puse la imagen en la descripción.

Comment: Cómo estás creando la dirección de descarga?
Tendrías que construirla para que te quedara algo como, `./descargas/archivo_nuevo.extension`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estás intentando escribir un archivo en la carpeta "descargas", pero no tienes permiso para hacerlo. Una posible solución es asegurarte de que tienes permisos de escritura en la carpeta "descargas" antes de intentar escribir en ella. Por ejemplo, puedes cambiar los permisos de la carpeta de la siguiente manera:

```
import os

download_folder = "./descargas"

# Cambia los permisos de la carpeta para permitir la escritura
os.chmod(download_folder, 0o777)

with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
```

También puedes intentar especificar una ruta de acceso absoluta en lugar de una ruta de acceso relativa al usar la función open(), lo que puede ayudar a evitar problemas de permisos. Por ejemplo:

```
# Obtiene la ruta absoluta de la carpeta "descargas"
download_folder = os.path.abspath("./descargas")

# Especifica la ruta absoluta al usar la función open()
with open(os.path.join(download_folder, "mi_archivo.txt"), "wb") as download_file:
    download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
```

Comment: Hola Cristian.
Muchas gracias, me funciono la segunda